ReedSolo error correction codec with bitstream as input
Does anyone know where to find open source code for a ReedSolo encoder that uses a binary bitstream as input? Preferably a Python project。
The open source projects I have found so far all use the ReedSolo encoding method with characters as input, (for example https://github.com/tomerfiliba-org/reedsolomon.) Is there a ReedSolo encoding method that uses binary bit streams as input?

bch code is bit oriented, but a specific implementation will be for a specific number of bits. Is there a reason the bit stream can't be grouped into characters or symbols (8 to 16 bits)?

It is indeed possible to convert the bit stream into a character stream for processing, and I have already implemented this process. However, this seems to cause some waste. For example, if the bits I transmit are not 8 or 16 bits, the information stream still needs to be converted into the corresponding character stream. Can RS only process character stream input?

The stream would not need to transmit trailing zero bits to pad to character boundary, that can be done on the receiver side.
